# How to apply CDN with cloudfront - router 53 => lightsail instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, amazon-lightsail

i am newbie to AWS and i am struggling set up subdomain access , my materials are :

- **Route 53** : my domain is tranthanhbao.com
- **Lightsail instance** : 18.140.2.35 . I already set up nginx reverse proxy and in Route 53 point `aws.tranthanhbao.com` to 18.140.2.35 with A - ipv4  . It work well
  MY setting in Route 53 to 18.140.2.35 :
  [image]
- **Cloudfront** : now i want to apply cloudfront to my domain `aws.tranthanhbao.com` (http will redirect to https) with below setting
  [image]
  [image]

Then when we access [dsor8zoqxftko.cloudfront.net](http://dsor8zoqxftko.cloudfront.net/), it works well but i check domain ip , it show :

- [[http://dsor8zoqxftko.cloudfront.net/]](http://dsor8zoqxftko.cloudfront.net/) : this is from France and automatic redirect http to https. So it works well
  BUT
- [[http://aws.tranthanhbao.com/]](http://aws.tranthanhbao.com) : still http and from my Lightsail instance IP .

So my question is how can I apply `aws.tranthanhbao.com` with cloudfront, not Link: [http://dsor8zoqxftko.cloudfront.net/]

Comment: Have you tried creating a route 53 Alias? An alias is a type of CNAME that can be used for AWS resources (CloudFront distribution endpoint, S3 website endpoints, ELB endpoints). Your setup will be (your custom domain) -> (cloudfront) -> (lightsail).

Comment: Check the Yes box next to Alias. It is visible as No in your first screenshot. Paste the cloudfront url instead of the IP address,

Comment: I can not. I have to point aws.tranthanhbao.com to the instance IP then i can not point aws.tranthanhbao.com to cloudfront dist anymore (Err: duplicated) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below steps:

1. Point `18.140.2.35` to some other name like `origin.tranthanhbao.com origin.tranthanhbao.com` --> 18.140.2.35
2. Define `origin.tranthanhbao.com` as an Origin of CloudFront instead of `aws.tranthanhbao.com`
3. Modify Route Record for `aws.tranthanhbao.com` and Choose Alias record (A record) and choose CloudFront distribution.

Comment: So the flow would be Instance IP <= origin.tranthanhbao.com ( route 53 Alias : Instance IP) <= cloudfront distribution dsa2d22.cloudfront.net (CNAME: aws.tranthanhbao.com) . So origin.tranthanhbao.com is still exposed to internet with http ? Which mean we need 2 subdomain for 1 single cloudfront to work and the origin.tranthanhbao.com  is still accessible with http ?

Comment: Yes, there are ways to restrict origin.tranthanhbao.com direct access, e.g: Allowing only CloudFront IP addresses in the Security group.

Comment: along with add a custom header on cloudfront in origin configuration and allow requests only if the header is present https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/forward-custom-headers.html

Comment: Note that Lightsail security groups are not as advanced as EC2, so they only allow either "port open to 0.0.0.0/0" or "port not open" (default behavior).  The custom origin header check is a better solution.